# How can I create code that will enable auto-update of the range location when the Excel Model is updated and the location of the target cells changes?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created macro in Excel VBA to perform iterative operations. The intention of this code is to paste the values from one range of cells, which contain formulas, into another range.

In this code, I have specified the location of the ranges (both for the ones being copied and for the ones being pasted).

During the modification of the Excel Model, I change the number of rows or columns (by adding or deleting), thus changing the actual location of the range of cells. As an example, what used to be Range("N786:BT786") can become Range("N650:BT650").

I would certainly appreciate if you could help to modify my code so that the ranges would not be fixed to the static location, but rather automatically update as the model itself is being updated.

Thank you in advance.

Below you may find my code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub calculations_update()

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartTime As Double

Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

StartTime = Timer

Do While i < 95

    i = i + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Electrity").Activate

    Range("N786:BT786").Value = Range("N787: BT787").Value

    Range("R826:BT826").Value = Range("R827: BT827").Value

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Efficiency").Activate

    Range("H814").Value = Range("H815").Value

    Range("H826").Value = Range("H827").Value

    Range("H846").Value = Range("H847").Value

Loop

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

MsgBox "The update was successful in " &SecondsElapsed& " seconds", bInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to name the range and then use that name instead of the static cell address.

Comment: Hi there. I made this loop to iterate the process of copying and pasting 95 times.

Comment: Dear, YowE3K I am quite new to coding and I would immensely appreciate if you could help by suggesting the syntax for the code on couple of examples of the aforementioned iterations

Comment: Thanks - I reread the question and noticed you were iterating, so then realised that you had answered my question even before I asked - if only I had read the question properly.

Comment: Use Formulas / Name Manager to name cells "N787:BT787" to be something like "SourceRange1" and cells "N786:BT786" to be something like "DestRange1".  Then your code can use `Range("DestRange1").Value = Range("SourceRange1").Value`.  Then, as you insert / delete rows above those ranges, Excel will still keep those names pointing to the appropriate cells.

Comment: Thank you,  YowE3K, I will try this. Will I need to Declare these name ranges as variables or make other code modifications?

Comment: No, you give the ranges a name in Excel, and then your only code change is to replace your current names of "N787:BT787" with the names you assigned in Excel.

Comment: Thank you,  YowE3K, I just tried it, it works! This is so simple and genius! I appreciate it! Can you please offer overall recommendations on the code to make it smoother?

Comment: @JoshuaAdams since this is working code you will want to go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you would like it optimized.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid using static cell addresses within your code, it is usually better to assign names to the relevant cells (using Formulas / Name Manager within Excel) and then use those names in your code.

Assuming you assigned names (with "Workbook" scope) to your ranges as follows:

```
Range                          Name
Electricity!$N$786:$BT$786     DstRng1
Electricity!$N$787:$BT$787     SrcRng1
Electricity!$R$826:$BT$826     DstRng2
Electricity!$R$827:$BT$827     SrcRng2
Efficiency!$H$814              DstRng3
Efficiency!$H$815              SrcRng3
Efficiency!$H$826              DstRng4
Efficiency!$H$827              SrcRng4
Efficiency!$H$846              DstRng5
Efficiency!$H$847              SrcRng5
```

(obviously, you could use more meaningful names if you like)

the following code could be used:

```
Option Explicit

Sub calculations_update()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim StartTime As Double    
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim i As Long

    StartTime = Timer

    Do While i < 95
        i = i + 1
        Range("DstRng1").Value = Range("SrcRng1").Value
        Range("DstRng2").Value = Range("SrcRng2").Value
        Range("DstRng3").Value = Range("SrcRng3").Value
        Range("DstRng4").Value = Range("SrcRng4").Value
        Range("DstRng5").Value = Range("SrcRng5").Value
    Loop

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "The update was successful in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you not want to make those references absolute?  They will still change with additions and subtractions, but relative makes it relative to where there used on the worksheet, is it different in vba?  I do not use them very often.

Comment: @Joshua do you actually need to iterate 95 times?  or was this just part or your original solution?  Are these values being copied actually used in an iterative formula?

Comment: Super! This is awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ScottCraner thats the whole point...he wants the ranges to expand/move as he adds/removes rows/columns

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you are correct - I am so used to just naming them on the sheet itself that I forgot that Name Manager allows relative references

Comment: @Profex I think Scott is correct - a relative named range is relative to the "current" cell, but an absolute one becomes a fixed cell (but the "fixed cell" is still adjusted as cells are inserted/deleted)